# C# Datagridvew checkbox value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, checkbox

I want to get a checkbox value from a datagridview(True/False) but I always get a value "null", here is the code where i get the value of the checkbox:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell boolean = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
string checkCheckboxChecked = ((bool)boolean.FormattedValue) ? "False" : "True";
```

This code returns a `false`  in the `Boolean.FormattedValue` even the checkbox is checked
and also I tried another:

```
object value = dgvVisual[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
```

And this code return a value of null

Why does this happen?

P.S. `e` is an event of the `CELL CONTENT CLICK`.

Here is the full code of the datagridview cell content click:

```
private void dgvVisual_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int Number1= int.Parse(dgvVisual[0, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    int Number2 = (e.ColumnIndex - 1);                
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell boolean = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dgvVisual[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
    bool checkCheckboxChecked = (null != boolean && null != boolean.Value && true == (bool)boolean.Value);
    //string checkCheckboxChecked = "";
    if (checkCheckboxChecked)
    {
        //do something if the checkbox is checked
    }
    else
    {
        //do something if the checkbox isn't
    }
}
```

SOLVED:
I changed the `CELL END EDIT EVENT` and add the click content to `datagridview.CurrentCell` to another cell.

Comment: Try dgvVisual[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.toString();

Comment: NULL Reference exception if i use dgvVisual[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.toString();

Comment: Since you are using an eventargs which DataGridView event is this code in?

Comment: e is an event of DatagridView CELL CONTENT CLICK

Comment: use the dgv_CellEndEdit event instead

Comment: Problem sovled using the CELL END EDIT event but it's weird as the user have to click another cell after clicking the checkbox on the original one

Comment: Try the `DataGridView.CellValueChanged` event I'm thinking it might do the trick.

Comment: Problem solved by changing the event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bit odd calling the cell boolean. And then using its `FormattedValue` property. I added a `DataGridView` to a Form, added two columns `Text` and `Checkbox`. `CheckBox` is a `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`. Then I added a button and this should give you the idea:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Text");
    dt.Columns.Add("CheckBox");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = i.ToString();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    dgv.DataSource = dt;            
}

private void dgv_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
    {
        var oCell = row.Cells[1] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
        bool bChecked = (null != oCell && null != oCell.Value && true == (bool)oCell.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: is OCELL a DataGridViewCheckBoxCell?

Comment: This doesn't work also, It returns a "FALSE" value even the checkbox is checked

Comment: It doesn't work for me also...is it that i blind the data from the database and i changed the Column's data property name?